# I have android 7 but i cant locate factory reset protection(FRP)

Tags: frp

I have android 7 on my device but i am cant find how i can enable FRP.

I was thinking that all devices above 5 have FRP protection app as the settings ought to have cloud and accounts menu that i can find the FRP support.

Is this to be expected?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Factory Reset Protection (FRP) is invisible and if it is present always active.

You only have to add one Google Account into the Android account list to "bind" your device to this account.

If the factory reset protection works or not you will only see if you perform a factory reset of such a device. If after the factory reset it asks for the password of that Google account it is active.

Comment: Most chinese made devices i have tested with have not this feature. You can pretty much factory reset even if you have 10 accounts attached to the device.